# Regex to match everything outside of main function

Tags: javascript, regex, codemirror

I'm currently using CodeMirror, with **javascript**, which seems not to support lookahead or lookbehind. I can **only provide a RegEx** to CodeMirror, without any code, and it'll highlight what is matched.

The user is supposed to be writing everything inside a single function, which is considered to be the "root" function.

For example, this is right :

```
=FUNCTION(X="t")
```

And this is not :

```
=FUNCTION(X="t")=()
```

I need to create a regex that matches everything outside of "**=FUNCTION(...)**", so in this context, "**=()**" without using lookbehind or lookahead.

The desired result should match this :

```
=FUNCTION(...)=()
              ^^^
```

```
=FUNCTION(X="t")=()
                ^^^
```

```
=FUNCTION(X="t"()()())=()
                      ^^^
```

```
=FUNCTION(X="t"()()())=(()=()
                      ^^^^^^^
```

```
=FUNCTION(X="t"()()())=XXXXXX
                      ^^^^^^^
```

```
=FUNCTION(X="t"""()()())=XXXXXX
                        ^^^^^^^
```

```
=FUNCTION(X="t"""()()(), X()="b")=XXXXXX
                                 ^^^^^^^
```

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: please provide your desired result

Comment: It is provided in the post. Should I format it differently?

Comment: What if the syntax is wrong, like when parentheses or quotes are not balanced? What is the language that is encoded there?

Comment: I've added some details in the post. I'm using javascript.

Comment: It will be quite easy if you are looking everything after the 2nd `=` sign

Comment: I've added more examples in the post, as this (the fact that I can have "=" between parenthesis) is something I did not mention

Comment: @Pandorque thanks for adding the desired results, so my answer is ready

Comment: It seems it's only possible if the regex supports [PCRE syntax](https://regex101.com/r/N5ubTD/1)

Comment: The OP might consider that regex most probably is not the right tool, despite being the only one available. Whatever pattern gets provided here, the chances of a failure at any given time are much bigger than zero.

Comment: He needs something like C# regex that can match balanced groups to handle the parenthesis inside of parenthesis.

Comment: The C# regex `(?:=FUNCTION\((?:[^()]+|(?<open>\()|(?<-open>\)))+(?(open)(?!))\))(.*)` This will match the function and all the stuff after - group 1 is the part after.  https://regex101.com/r/d8Ju5O/1  Maybe someone knows how to put the non capture group into a lookbehind...

Answer (score 0):

Use capture groups. For internal brackets use an optional non-captured group:

`(.*)` - anything before the function, remove if not needed
`=FUNCTION\(` - the function declaration
`[^()]*` - anything before the first parenthesis in the function
`(?:.*\([^()]*\))*` - any number of matching parentheses and anything between the closed parentheses.
`[^()]*` - anything before the function's closing parenthesis
`\)` - the closing parenthesis
`(.*)` - anything after the function

```js
const regex = /(.*)=FUNCTION\([^()]*(?:.*\([^()]*\))*[^()]*\)(.*)/;

const match = str => console.log(JSON.stringify(str.match(regex).slice(1)));

match('prefix =FUNCTION(X="t"()()())=(()=()');
match('=FUNCTION(X="t"""()()(), X()="b")=XXXXXX');
match('=FUNCTION(X="t"""()()(), X()="b")');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but there is still one remaining problem here for me ; the way CodeMirror works is that I can only provide a regex, and no code for it, it'll simply highlight what is matched.  I'll add this information into the original post, sorry if this wasn't clear.

Comment: @Pandorque afaik it's not possible to include only the captured groups in the result. so seems impossible to do that with a regex only and without assertions